# Is it ok to concatenate variables with strings when appending to DOM? Does it take care of escaping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

Me and my colleague were having this debate where he states that concatenating strings and variables and using them in jQuery `append()` poses no risk in terms of XSS. However, I believe that variables containing untrusted data must be escaped prior to appending the same to the DOM. And default jQuery functions such as `text`, `attr`, `html`, etc do a good job of escaping.

Colleague’s version of the code:

```
$('#container').append('<div data-someData="' + untrustedData + '">' + untrustedTEXT + '<img src="' + untrustedIMGSRC + '" /></div>');
```

My version:

```
/* First append the HTML structure */
$('#container').append('<div><img /></div>');

/* Now assign variables using jQuery functions such as `attr`, `data`, etc */
$('#container div').data('someData', untrustedData);
$('#container div').text(untrustedTEXT);
$('#container div img').attr('src', untrustedIMGSRC);
```

My version of code increases the code footprint but IMO handles the necessary escaping to prevent XSS. Am I correct in my assumptions or is my colleague correct. Or are we both doing it the wrong way?

Comment: I think you're both really confused, and should read more about XSS.

Comment: `text` and `attr` do escaping, `html` and `append` do not.

Comment: @adeneo Essentially, I'm looking at the fact that any untrusted data when injected to DOM could result in XSS, if the browser chooses to run the data instead of displaying it. Escaping the variable would prevent the browser from running the code. Could you elaborate on why you think that my or my colleague's understanding of XSS may be flawed?

Comment: The issue isn't escaping data before appending it, the issue here would be, where is the data coming from, and how would someone be able to insert code into that data that can be executed on other users instance of the script etc. As long as you're working with local data on the clientside, or secure data from your server, there is no way anyone could inject code that would influence other users, so escaping content on the clientside is really not an issue, and it's not really very effective either.

Comment: @adeneo On server side data already runs through sanitization filters before even making it into the db. However, malicious code still could make it into the system unless you are using a robust HTML sanitizer such as HTML purifier (PHP). This warrants escaping data at output as an additional layer of protection. I'd like to understand under what scenarios can client side escaping be non-effective?

Comment: But if someone can put malicious code in your database, that's the issue, and then you're probably screwed. You shouldn't have to worry about escaping data on the clientside that you're getting from your own server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery `.text()` escapes the contents

jQuery `.html()` does not escape the contents

jQuery `.append()` and it's relatives do not escape the contents

Comment: Would that mean that my implementation of the code above is correct?

Comment: That option appears to accomplish your goals, yes.